# Oracle Apex 5.1 - Interactive Grid Date Picker - TypeError: rec is null - BUG?

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm getting a JavaScript Error everytime I change a value for a DatePicker Element in a Interactive Grid.

I tried to set up the IG from Scratch with the Wizard - did not help

IG consist of just 5 columns where 2 of them are DatePicker Elements.

The table is PK based.

I set up an example with the same table on apex.oracle.com:

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=63527:2

Workspace: HEIFIHEIFI
User: TEST
Pwd: TEST

To get the error just change the dates 2 times and hit save.

IG Datepicker Error

[image]

Comment: I tried and there was no errors. Do you still have an error?

Comment: Also tried and had no errors.

Comment: Thanks for testing, I keep getting the error, I do the following:
Open Console to the the error (Apex Debug Mode to see the full error) Change Next Check Date==> Change IS Checked Date==> Save ==> Try to change another column or just click into the IG ==> Error occurs.